# Minio does not recognize credentials when loaded from Kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, minio, kubernetes-secrets

I am running a minio deployment in a Kubernetes Cluster.
I used to have the access- and secret key in clear text in the yaml files as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minio
spec:
...
      containers:
        - name: minio
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: "/data"
          image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-04-06T23-11-00Z
          args:
            - gateway
            - nas
            - /data
          env:
            - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
              value: "minio"
            - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
              value: "mysupersecretkey"
...
```

This works fine.
However when I move the credetials into a kubernetes secret, minio does no longer recognize these credetials, even though they are loaded into the same environment variables:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
      containers:
        - name: minio
          ...
          env:
            - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: minio-secret
                  key: minioAccessKey
            - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: minio-secret
                  key: minioSecretKey
...
```

I can confirm, that these credentials get mounted properly into the container as environment variables:

```sh
$ echo $MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
minio
$ echo $MINIO_SECRET_KEY
mysupersecretkey
```

But minio does not recognize these credentials:

[image: minio error]

Is there any difference, to how these variables are used, when they originate from a kubernetes secret?

**EDIT**

I have also tried with the `MINIO_ROOT_USER` and `MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD` variables, as the docs suggest. However, resulting in the same error using kubernetes secrets and no error with clear text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, which was caused by the way the credentials were written into the Kubernetes secrets.
It turned out, that the tools I was using appended a `\n (0x0a)` newline character to the base64 encoded secret.

This is why the credentials never matched what I entered into the login UI.